# "TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function" in nopCommerce 3.40

Tags: jquery, nopcommerce, magnific-popup

The following code displays picture thumb nails and attaches a magnificPopup event. it also embeds a picture within a picture.

This all worked a few days ago but now broken it somehow and now all i get is a js type error.

I have tried fiddling around with `jQuery.noConflict()` even though i have not added any new libs or updated old ones but that of course did nothing. i know that the problem has to do with magnificPopup somehow because if i simply remove the script from the code everything works fine again.

I guess i made a simple error somewhere which leads to this but i can't find anything and i've looked all day. any pointers are appreciated.

```
@model ProductDetailsModel
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Media
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
@{
   Html.AddCssFileParts("~/Content/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css");
   Html.AddScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js");
}

...   

var backThumb = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(lPictures[1], 100);
var backPic = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(lPictures[1]);

<a class="thumb-popup-link" id="thumb-popup-link-back" title="@Model.PictureModels[0].Title">
    <img id="backThumb" alt="@Model.PictureModels[0].AlternateText" src="@backThumb" title="@Model.PictureModels[0].Title Back Thumb" />
</a>
<div id="backview" class="mfp-hide" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-right: -50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
   <img id="backPic" src="@backPic" alt="@Model.PictureModels[0].AlternateText Back" />
   <div id="logoBox" style="position: absolute; top: 277px; width: 319px; left: 729px; height: 328px;">
       <img id="logoPic" src="/Themes/Motion/Content/img/logo.gif" alt="@Model.PictureModels[0].AlternateText Logo Box" title="logo" style="max-width: 320px; max-height: 330px; vertical-align: middle; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-bottom: -50%; margin-right: -50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)" />
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#thumb-popup-link-front').magnificPopup({
                 items:
                 {
                     src: '#frontview',
                     closeOnContentClick: true
                 },
                 type: 'inline'
             });
          });
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#thumb-popup-link-back').magnificPopup({
                 items:
                 {
                     src: '#backview',
                     closeOnContentClick: true
                 },
                 type: 'inline'
             });
          });
</script>
```

Edit 1: I added the top of the razor class code to show how the magnific-popup lib is being loaded.

Edit 2:

```
    <link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/mobile-only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/480.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/768.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/980.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/CSS/forum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Themes/Motion/Content/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Scripts/fineuploader/fineuploader-4.2.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.AjaxCart/Styles/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.AjaxCart/Themes/Motion/Content/ajaxCart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.ProductRibbons/Styles/Ribbons.common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.ProductRibbons/Themes/Motion/Content/Ribbons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.ajaxcart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fineuploader/jquery.fineuploader-4.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Core/Scripts/jquery.styleSelect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Core/Scripts/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Core/Scripts/SevenSpikesExtensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.AjaxCart/Scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.AjaxCart/Scripts/AjaxCart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.userevents.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.draganddrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.window.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.ProductRibbons/Scripts/jquery.json-2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.ProductRibbons/Scripts/ProductRibbons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Plugins/SevenSpikes.Core/Scripts/footable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Themes/Motion/Content/scripts/Motion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You must have removed the import of `magnificPopup` plugin. (Look, same error: http://jsfiddle.net/furv6tq0/)

Comment: yeah. i've just done that.

i added some info about the magnificPopup loading process.

Comment: Ok so you showed us where you've told your razor view to output that plugin, what does the rendered html look like? Does it have a `<script>` tag pointing to the right path for that plugin?

Comment: i've added the top part of the page source where the scripts are actually loaded.

Comment: i have found out that magnific-popup is really not loaded at all. at least it doesn't show up in the firefox debugger. i have no idea why this is happening though. i'll add the script src in front of the script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was SOME addon of mine. Probably noscript or request policy... I've yet to figure out which one prevented a single js library from being loaded. That explains why it suddenly stopped working. The addon must have been updated and started to cause issues.

This is bad... really bad. If those addons start to interfere with websites even though I have explicitly put them on my white list something is going terribly wrong.

Sorry for all the noise. Maybe the thread still helps someone.

Comment: Had a similar issue, in my case it just was blocked by my adblocker.