# Magnific Popup blocked by Adblock (uBlock)

Tags: javascript, nopcommerce, magnific-popup, adblock

The open source shopping platform NopCommerce uses magnific popup (mp) on various occasions. I found that since a few days mp is being blocked by either Adblock Edge and uBlock. Certain pages become unusable since scripts that are usually loaded after mp are not loaded at all any longer. This happens because the browser will throw an exception on not being able to find the function mp exposes to use its functionality:

```
TypeError: $(…).magnificPopup is not a function
```

This basically breaks any web page using adblock and mp together.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function" in nopCommerce 3.40](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028932/typeerror-magnificpopup-is-not-a-function-in-nopcommerce-3-40)